# jQuery cycle through element attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

Using jQuery, considering the variable **dxl** is an array of links to .pdf files, how can I cycle the values of the dxl array, in an element's attribute, when a button is clicked?

Example:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"> Push </a>
```

**jQuery**

```
var dxl = ["d.pdf", "x.pdf", "l.pdf"];

$("a").click(function(){
    $("#button").attr("href", dxl);
    $("#button").attr("download", pdf_name);
});
```

Looking to download 3 .pdf files after **Push** button is clicked; cycling the array values in the `href` attribute. Button is clicked, `href` receives the first array value, downloads it, then next array value is passed to `href` (without having to click button again).

Comment: You could just create a temporary `a` element for every file, and click it through javascript if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through an array:

```
dxl.map(function(val){
   console.log(val); //will print d.pdf, x.pdf and l.pdf
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method i think, is to open the files in separate new windows, because `http` do not support downloading multiple files.

```
var dxl = ["d.pdf", "x.pdf", "l.pdf"];
$("a").click(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < dxl.length; i++){
        window.open(dxl[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work...

```
var dxl = ['d.pdf', 'x.pdf', 'l.pdf'];

for(var href of dxl){
  console.log(href);

  jQuery('#button').attr('href',href);
  jQuery('#button').trigger('click');
}
```